# Changing DNS settings on Android doesn't work

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns

My device is [a LeMaker Guitar Kit](http://www.lenovator.com/product/96.html). I do not have root access on the device. I followed the guide from [XSLAB - How to Change DNS Settings on Android](http://xslab.com/2013/08/how-to-change-dns-settings-on-android/) to change the DNS. I am accessing my WiFi at home. When I set my DNS on my Android device and go to [DNS leak test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/results.html), it's not the DNS that I set in the DNS settings. It's the DNS set by my ISP.

**How can I get it to use the DNS that I want?**

---

Maybe I need to have root and/or use an app like the one mentioned on [How to change mobile connections's DNS on Android KitKat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62081/how-to-change-mobile-connectionss-dns-on-android-kitkat) - Override DNS. Also need to work out what version of Android it is, but think it is the most recent version.

Related question on [Change DNS but stay on DHCP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125954/change-dns-but-stay-on-dhcp) leaving the IP as dynamic (currently giving it static IP from the router) and using apps to change the DNS.

Related question on [where are DNS settings under 4.4.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148354/where-are-dns-settings-under-4-4-2), but he can't save the new DNS settings.

A possible option from [Can't change DNS on S3 mini](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109269/cant-change-dns-on-s3-mini), in one of the answers is use debugging mode and adb to change the DNS settings, but my problem is not changing the DNS, it is getting the DNS I change it to work.

Comment: Might Help:  **[\[GUIDE\] How to Change DNS in Android Device (8 methods)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/xda-university/guide-how-to-change-dns-android-device-t3273769)**

Comment: [How to configure DNS properly?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526)

Answer (score 2):

First you must have [**dnscrypt**](https://dnscrypt.org/#dnscrypt-android) installed.
These scripts require root access:

```
#!/bin/sh
#root is required 

#daemonize dnscrypt
dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize --resolver-address=208.67.220.220:443 --provider-name=2.dnscrypt-cert.opendns.com --provider-key=B735:1140:206F:225D:3E2B:D822:D7FD:691E:A1C3:3CC8:D666:8D0C:BE04:BFAB:CA43:FB79

#this will redirect dns query traffics to localhost
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

If you want to restore DNS to default, run this:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the DNS but you will need to set a static IP as well. If you long press on the WiFi name you can change the options from there.

Comment: tks, I have done that,  but it is not using the dns I set it to when I go to dns leak test.

Comment: Try a restart of the device and also toggling Airplane Mode.

Comment: tks, pretty sure I treid all that, but I'll have another go.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, in addition to using settings. You can still use a third-party application to change DNS. Such as:

1. DNS Changer | Mobile Data & WiFi | IPv4 & IPv6
2. Net Optimizer | Optimize Your Internet Speed
3. DNS Smart Changer - Web content blocker and filter
4. 1.1.1.1: Faster & Safer Internet
5. Turbo VPN- Free VPN Proxy Server & Secure Service

Answer (score 0):

This question (2016) is 6 years old and I had the same problem recently. Because I used my own DNS server (BIND 9), I finally found that there was a problem with the BIND settings. According to the prompts in `/var/log/named/named.log`, I corrected my own DNS server settings and the problem was solved.